# Setting up image gallery using javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm just starting out learning javascript and I'm having a hard time with this. I have 3 images that all share a class attribute of "preview" I am trying to write a javascript function that when I mouseover any of the images I get the source of the image and use that the set the background-image: url(''); in my css of a different div to the source of that image so that it displays the image in the other div. I've been looking for an answer and I may be asking the wrong questions. This is what I currently have:

```
function upDate(previewPic){
  var img = document.getElementClassName("preview").getAttribute('src');

  img.onmouseover = function() {
    document.getElementById("image").style.backgroundImage = img; 
  }
}
```

what would be a better way to accomplish this?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Photo Gallery</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/gallery.css">
    <script src = "js/gallery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id = "image">
        Hover over an image below to display here.
    </div>

    <img class = "preview" alt = "Styling with a Bandana" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon.jpg" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

    <img class = "preview" alt = "With My Boy" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon2.JPG" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

    <img class = "preview" src = "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/389177/bacon3.jpg" alt = "Young Puppy" onmouseover = "upDate(this)" onmouseout = "unDo()">

    <script src="js/index.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please, post your HTML file as well as correct your code with the code blocks. Elements in HTML must have unique IDs, so you can't have 3 images that share the id "Image"

Comment: IDs must be unique in the document.

Comment: Your code has `getElementById("preview")` but in your question you said preview was a class.